# Passing no-sandbox but still getting error 'Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported.`

Tags: docker, puppeteer

I was able to get it working using the `node` user and setting up a sandbox using `--cap-add=SYS_ADMIN` but AWS ECS Fargate does not support adding `SYS_ADMIN` as a  linux parameter. Therefore, I am trying to pass `no--sandbox` to puppeteer so I can run as root but am still getting the error `Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported`.

#### Environment

- Puppeteer version: 1.20.0
- Platform / OS version: Docker/Debian 9.12
- Node.js version: 10.21

#### Steps to reproduce

If I exec into the Docker container and explicitly run `node puppeteer.js` I do not get the error but if I make a request to my container via Postman (http://localhost:8081) I get the error.

**Dockerfile**

```sh
FROM node:10.21

RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 \
  libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 \
  libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 \
  libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 \
  libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 \
  libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates \
  fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget


# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

# Install app dependencies
RUN npm install

# Tried running as node user 
#USER node

# Provide google authentication credentials to your application code
ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/usr/src/app/google/keys.json

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

**Puppeteer.js**

```sh
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

/**
 * Initializes and returns a puppeteer instance
 * @name {getPuppeteerInstance}
 * @returns {Promise} resolves with puppeteer instance
 */
module.exports = async () => {
  try {
    const options = {
      headless: true,
      args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
      defaultViewport: {
        width: 1440,
        height: 900,
      },
      timeout: 0,  // 0ms timeout is no timeout 
    };
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(options);
    const page = await browser.newPage(); ``

    page.setDefaultTimeout(0);
    page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);

    return { browser, page };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`error`, error);

    return {};
  }
};
```

**What is the expected result?**
By passing `--no-sandbox` I would expect that would be able to launch puppeteer as root without setting up a sandbox with no issues.

**What happens instead?**

```sh
error Error: Failed to launch chrome!
blackbox-app | [0113/220603.530554:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
```

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm getting the same problem

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here, tried couple of things to make this work

Dockerfile

Enable kernel

```
RUN echo 'kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1' > /etc/sysctl.d/userns.conf
```

Add user and start chromium with that user

```
RUN adduser --disabled-password --disabled-login puppeteer

USER puppeteer

CMD ["your command"]
```

In docker-compose.yaml

```
    cap_add:
      - SYS_ADMIN
```